# Allowing a user to choose which image style they want for a single uploaded image

Tags: nodes, media

I have a views list showing a set of property's displaying address, image, description and price in a horizontal manner, each line is a new listing for a property.

the user simply uploads an image and clicks save. however I have recently been asked to allow for the user to again upload a single image, only this time select an image style that contains an an overlay or watermark image on top of the uploaded image.

I have managed to create the image styles with a watermark effect for each overlay image they requested such as "Available now", "Under Offer" ect. But I have absolutely no idea how I provide a choice for the user to select one of these image styles.

so to clarify the user would like to upload an image and then select a pre made image style under that uploaded image to apply a watermark over the top. I am having trouble providing a choice for the user to select. everything else has been achieved.

I hope this makes sense I have tried to be as detailed as i can and hope there is a solution to this. Thank you for everyone's time.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an additional field to your content type that stores the values of the image style presets on your site. This will allow them to select which image style they want once they've uploaded an image.

You'll need to write a small custom module to pull the existing image style presets from the database and programatically populate the allowed values of the in your new select field.

You can create a custom node or views template and use the value of the image style field to display the uploaded image with the selected image style.